# Dealing with the result of an Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragmenttransaction

As it stands, my app is/was currently processing an http post and some other stuff in an Async task, and then when the task is completed and onPostExecute is called I would attempt to redirect to another fragment via a fragment transaction. This has proven pretty tricky, and I am looking alternatives to handling this situation without attempting to commit transactions in onPostExecute. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the method being called from onPostExecute...

```
private void callback(boolean submissionSuccessful)
{
    if (submissionSuccessful)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment f =  new CompletedFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("id", reportToSubmit.getReferenceId());

        f.setArguments(args);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, f, "completed").commit();


    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.report_error), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The reason for this is as follows: User completes a wizard (ViewPager), submits, a progress dialog is shown while processing, and when completed onPostExecute commits a confirmation fragment that let's the user know the process is complete.

Comment: Please show: 1. How you're handling stuff now, and 2. Whay exactly has proven tricky?

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect this information now.

Answer (score 0):

The logic looks pretty good. I'm not sure what you would want to change.

2 things:

- You might want to tell your `Activity` to do the transition (move the callback method). This decouples this Fragment from the second, which is considered 'good practice'.
- Second, in `onPostExecute`, your `Fragment` *might not* be attached to the `Activity` anymore, and `getActivity()` will return `null`. You could cancel the `AsyncTask` in `onPause`, or check for `isAdded` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: The strange thing is that, using this code, sometimes when my Async method is done it moves the completed fragment and I see it, but other times it skips the view of the completed fragment. That is now my main issue, that and the fear of commit() throwing an illegal state exception if by chance it is called after onsaveInstance() is called.